# Clip shapefile with shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, clip, intersect

There are two shapefiles. One is a compilation of municipalities on the coast with borders extending into ocean. The second shapefile is a coastal border.

I'm trying to clip the municipality shapefile with the coastal border shapefile to remove the municipality sea territory from my image, but I've had little success. The municipality boundaries are contiguous, so the coastal border on the second shapefile needs to cut and remove the excess shape.

I'm using QGIS 2.14.3-Essen. I've googled around and tried several strategies. I've used a lot of the GeoProcessing Tools (difference, intersect, clip, union) and what returned was an invisible shapefile.

What should I try to make it work?

---

Below is a copy of the screen settings for the clip. The results was yet another invisible layer.

[image]

Below this is a screencap of municipality boundaries to be cut (CITY) and the coastline in red to cut them (SMC_BORDER).

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to specify **exactly** what you have tried and what resulted.

Comment: @Vince I've edited my question.

Comment: Please include the exact version of software in use and specify whether you have verified the geometry topology  (ring orientation) of the shapefile's polygons.

Comment: Have you checked the projections are the same and such? It might be helpful if you describe a specific workflow in more detail and describe what  steps you take - that can help folks determine what's going wrong.

Comment: @Vince, I've edited to include my software version. I'm not sure what you mean by the verified geometry topology.

Comment: @mtreg, what do you mean by projections? And I'm not sure how to get more specific. D:

Comment: Under vector>geometry run 'check validity'.  Are your geometries valid?  I'm thinking this is your problem.  Run that and let us know what happens.

Comment: by projections, they mean that your shapefiles may have different projections.  A projection is the method of converting the curved surface of the earth to a flat piece of paper (or computer screen).  If the files don't have the same projection, the clip isn't going to work properly.

Comment: Any chance the data are publicly available and you can provide links?

Comment: Your coastal boarder shapefile needs to be a closed polygon for the clip to work.  It is a polygon and not a polyline, correct?  If you try to clip polygons with a line, you'll get an empty file back.

Comment: Both geometries are valid (0 errors) and are the same projection--the maps align perfectly and are Psuedo Mercator. How could I double check that the polygon is closed? (Is that the validity check?)

Comment: Yes the validity check would have picked it up.  The clip should work.  Can you please run the clip operation again and post a screenshot of your settings (edit your question to include it) and any errors.  Also if you can, please show a screenshot of the data.

Comment: For the clip - input layer is your polygons, clip layer is the coastal boundary

Comment: @jbalk I've attached the images requested. I'm not entirely sure why this problem persists.

Comment: Your SMBC border looks quite funky, especially in the North. Install the geometry checker and/or the topology checker plugins and test again.

Comment: You're right it was the border that was problematic. I imported a coastline shapefile from the county and used "Difference" and managed to get what I needed.